# LWC Template tag not working for conditions

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom, html5

```
<template  if: true= {isFlagValue}>
```

showing some content on page when isFlagValue true but after getting false value for isFlagValue I am able to see content

### Heading

Answer (score 1):

Do not use spaces after the `:` or `=`. It must be `if:true={isFlagValue}`. Note that `if:true` and `if:false` are deprecated. You should instead use `lwc:if`, as in `lwc:if={isFlagValue}`.